# Can't add content?

Tags: nodes, files, entities, search

I'm using Drupal 7.21. I have a content type called Video with a node title and a video field where I put the URL of the youtube video I want ([Video Embed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) module).

Everything went fine until I installed some modules like Video field and I uninstalled the Drupal core search.

Then when I want to add or modify a node I encounter this error:

```
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7633 of /homez.577/mySite/www/includes/common.inc).
```

and another error like so:

```
Notice: Undefined index: node in node_form_submit_build_node() (line 463 of /homez.577/mySite/www/modules/node/node.pages.inc).
```

Is there any solution for this?

**Notes**:

- I also noticed that when I uninstall the video CCK field, everything goes fine, but I need it ...
- I also use the [CCK Video](https://www.drupal.org/project/cck_video) module.

Comment: Have you checked the database as there might be some redundant table for the fields.. like http://drupal.org/node/1778572 and http://drupal.org/node/1277376

Comment: yes but i doesn't work, i mentionned that i unistalled the search api on my website